# How to wrap with <p> in first line of contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html

I used below code to wrap `<p>` instead of `<div>`.

```
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p')
```

But I still can't wrap first line, like this "aaa".

```
<div id=“body-text” class=“body-text” contenteditable=“true” data-placeholder=“Body Contents">
    aaa
    <p>bbb</p>
    <p>ccc</p>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to wrap first line "aaa" with `<p>`?

**postscript**

I changed my cord using one of the answer for reference.
But now I cant type any letter. Only if I press enter first, it works. But after I press enter and make `<p>`, I cant type any letter again.

Where is the problem?

```
<div id='body-text' class='body-text' contenteditable=true data-placeholder='Body Contents' onkeydown={firstLine}></div>
<script>
firstLine(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == '13') {
        var div = document.getElementById('body-text')
        var text = div.firstChild.textContents
        div.removeChild(div.firstChild)
        var p = document.createElement('p')
        p.textContent = text
        div.insertBefore(p, div.firstChild)
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please include your code as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: I did. Is this better?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `element.firstChild` to select the "aaa" textNode, and creating the paragraph element which then gets prepended back into `.body-text`.

```js
var pElement = document.createElement('p');
var bodyText = document.querySelector('.body-text');
var firstLine = bodyText.firstChild;

pElement.appendChild(firstLine);
bodyText.prepend(pElement);

console.log(bodyText.outerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="body-text" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Body Contents">
  aaa
  <p>bbb</p>
  <p>ccc</p>
</div>
```

***note:*** you don't need a class and an ID... choose one

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! When I run your code snippet, I got error. Is this correct?
And I want to know how to fire event too. Could you see my postscript and give me advice?

Comment: You've changed your question. Instead, remove the changes, choose an answer, post another question referencing this one with the new problems.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to get first text node of your div, save the text, remove that node and then create a p tag with the text from your ancient node and insert it in your div.

UPDATED

you had a little typpo problem `var text = div.firstChild.textContents`, there is no s it only `var text = div.firstChild.textContent`

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2rgLzkyj/

HTML :

```
<div id='body-text' class='body-text' contenteditable=true data-placeholder='Body Contents'>
  aaa
  <p>bbb</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var div = document.getElementById('body-text')

div.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);

function onKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {
        var text = div.firstChild.textContent;
        div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.textContent = text;
        div.insertBefore(p, div.firstChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I almost understood how to make it. But now I have another problem about event handler I think. I described my situation above.
Do you know what problem is?

Comment: see my update, and tell if it's not working or if you don't understand something

Comment: It almost works. On your code I press "aaa" and Enter, first line will be "" and second will be aaa. I want to delete this first line but I dont know how.. Do you know?

Comment: just add 'e.preventDefault();' after 'if (e.keyCode == '13') {'  if you want to remove the new line on enter

Comment: If I do so, it all doesnt work. Your previous one is almost perfect. Second line should be new line but first line looks like new line on your previous one since first line is null and second line has letter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first I have to let you know that the code you provided was using those fancy quotes `“` and `”` you must use either this `"` or this `'`. Having said that, I have made a Snippet that uses [`formatBlock`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

1. Highlight the text and click the button <kbd><p/></kbd>.
2. It can wrap text in a `<p>`, `<div>`, `<blockquote>`, `<h1>`, etc..

#### SNIPPET

```html
<div id="body-text" class="body-text" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Body Contents">
  aaa
  <p>bbb</p>
  <p>ccc</p>
</div>

<input type="button" class="p" onclick="document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p')" value="<p/>" title="Insert a Paragraph Wrapped on Highlighted Text">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!
Now I have another problem. Could you see my postscript and give me advice?

Comment: The answer I gave you matches your current setup more closely than the other solutions. Originally, you were using `.execCommand` hence my answer involved using that same interface. The answer you are having problems with involves the DOM and hardly anything with `execCommand`. In fact the only thing my solution and the other solutions have in common is that they all manipulate text...*how* our solutions manipulate text is entirely different.